# SQL With... Update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, with-statement

Is there any way to do some kind of "`WITH...UPDATE`" action on SQL?

For example:

```
WITH changes AS
  (...)
UPDATE table
SET id = changes.target
FROM table INNER JOIN changes ON table.id = changes.base
WHERE table.id = changes.base;
```

Some context information: What I'm trying to do is to generate a `base`/`target` list from a table and then use it to change values in another table (changing values equal to `base` into `target`)

Thanks!

Comment: so why don't you use the with's query itself in the update command?

Comment: You can't use `with` in an `update`, it's only valid for `select`. You could use `merge`, but not if you're really joining and updating the same value, `id` in this case; are your join and where clauses both really referring to `changes.base`?

Comment: @user2511414 Would you please give an example to check if that's what I'm looking for?

Comment: exactly replace the with select command ( . . . ) with changes (after inner join) in the update command, and beware about a alias

Comment: @AlexPoole Not really, as I'm experimenting with what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do is to change each row's `id` field from `base` to  `target` (each `base` to its corresponding `target`; rows with other `id` values are not affected).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `merge`, with the equivalent of your `with` clause as the `using` clause, but because you're updating the field you're joining on you need to do a bit more work; this:

```
merge into t42
using (
  select 1 as base, 10 as target
  from dual
) changes
on (t42.id = changes.base)
when matched then
update set t42.id = changes.target;
```

.. gives error:

```
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "T42"."ID"
```

Of course, it depends a bit what you're doing in the CTE, but as long as you can join to your table withint that to get the `rowid` you can use that for the `on` clause instead:

```
merge into t42
using (
  select t42.id as base, t42.id * 10 as target, t42.rowid as r_id
  from t42
  where id in (1, 2)
) changes
on (t42.rowid = changes.r_id)
when matched then
update set t42.id = changes.target;
```

If I create my `t42` table with an `id` column and have rows with values 1, 2 and 3, this will update the first two to 10 and 20, and leave the third one alone.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d204e/1).

It doesn't have to be `rowid`, it can be a real column if it uniquely identifies the row; normally that would be an `id`, which would normally never change (as a primary key), you just can't use it and update it at the same time.